# Git: file keep appear in modified section, and can't commit it

Tags: git

I have file without any changes, but keeps appear in "Modified" files, when try to add it and then commit receives: `no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")`

file path: `../v2.7/app/Http/Controllers/Wokbits.php`

I even tried to make small modification in the file, then commit/push (successfully), but file back to appear in "Modified" files.

[image]

[image]

`git config -l` returns:

```
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
core.pager=less -r
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true
alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
alias.llg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%H %d%Creset%n%s%n%+b%C(bold blue)%an <%ae>%Creset %C(bold green)%cr (%ci)' --abbrev-commit
alias.d=diff
alias.master=checkout master
alias.spull=svn rebase
alias.spush=svn dcommit
alias.alias=!git config --list | grep 'alias\.' | sed 's/alias\.\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1\     => \2/' | sort
include.path=~/.gitcinclude
include.path=.githubconfig
include.path=.gitcredential
diff.exif.textconv=exif
credential.helper=osxkeychain
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=git@git.wokcraft.com:wokcraft/API.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
mwafi:v2.6 prins$
```

Run: `GIT_TRACE=true git add -v ../v2.7/app/HTTP/Controllers/Wokbits.php;echo exit status is $?;git status`

```
mwafi:v2.6 prins$ GIT_TRACE=true git add -v ../v2.7/app/HTTP/Controllers/Wokbits.php;echo exit status is $?;git status
12:02:44.979902 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'add' '-v' '../v2.7/app/HTTP/Controllers/Wokbits.php'
exit status is 0
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   ../v2.7/app/Http/Controllers/Wokbits.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
mwafi:v2.6 prins$
```

Comment: Have you setup any git alias or hooks that may change the status of this file? Like always reset or checkout it?

Comment: No, I didn't setup anything @ElpieKay

Comment: Since only these two files has been updated (As show in git status). Can you please try `git add -A` and `git commit -m "Message you would like to give"`

Comment: It just returns to appear in modified files, both other modified file and untracked file committed successfully and stop appear. @Shravan40

Comment: @mwafi Is the folder `v2.7` itself also a git repo?

Comment: No, the home of repo is `api` folder: `api/v2.7` @ElpieKay

Comment: @mwafi Could you show me the file list in `api/.git/hooks` as well as the output of `git config -l`?

Comment: @ElpieKay, added to the post

Comment: @mwafi How about the files in .git/hooks/? Is there a `pre-commit`, `prepare-commit-msg` or `commit-msg` ?

Comment: this are existed files in .git/hooks/: `applypatch-msg.sample`,`commit-msg.sample`,
`post-update.sample`,
`pre-applypatch.sample`,
`pre-commit.sample`,
`pre-push.sample`,
`pre-rebase.sample`,
`prepare-commit-msg.sample`,
`update.sample` @ElpieKay

Comment: @mwafi I tried to reproduce it. `git add ../v2.7/app/HTTP/Controllers/Wokbits.php` seems to have no effect. Could try agian with `GIT_TRACE=true git add -v ../v2.7/app/HTTP/Controllers/Wokbits.php;echo exit status is $?;git status`? And please update the question with the output.

Comment: @ElpieKay where to put `GIT_TRACE=true` ?

Comment: @mwafi just before `git add`

Comment: @ElpieKay post updated,

Comment: @mwafi it's very strange. `git add` exits successfully but no verbose info is output. Could you have another `git add` try in the root folder of this git? And please make sure there is no .git in v2.7/, app/, HTTP/, or Controllers/.

Comment: @ElpieKay, there is no .git in v2.7/ or app/ .. etc, Add other file in git root work fine.

Comment: @mwafi How about `cd ..;git add v2.7/app/HTTP/Controllers/Wokbits.php`? If it does not work, try again with the `-f` option. If this cannot work either, I have no clues then. It's just beyond my git knowledge. Sorry.